# Stretching absolute parent P to its children width, when P is son of relative

Tags: html, css, layout

look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/QTrat/10/

I want to stretch the red box to the floated children combined width.

meaning, it should be:

```
child child child
```

instead of

```
child
child
child
```

how do I do it?

I don't mind changing the code completely as long as the layout is kept the same.

Comment: It's always a good idea to show your code, so people can see what to change and where ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it from floating to `display: inline-block`, and give the parent `white-space: nowrap`:

```
.middle-parent{
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;

    white-space: nowrap;                /* This */

    left: 0;            
}

.floated-child{
    display:inline-block;                     /* And this */

    background-color: beige;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/QTrat/12/

Answer (score 0):

just remove `position:absolute;` from `.middle-parent` 
you will find [this](http://jsfiddle.net/QTrat/13/). it may help you.

Comment: but then the top-parent is also expanded (maybe it wasn't clear that only the red box is supposed to be expanded).